# using LIMIT 0, 20 for infinite scroll - how to limit the number of total results?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a query:

```
 select * from table where id is not null order by desc LIMIT :start, :limit
```

the start and limit are there for the ajax infinite scroll / pagination to work

How can I limit the total results if im using limit already for the pagination?

I need a query similar to below:

```
select * from table where id is not null order by desc LIMIT :start, :limit LIMIT 5000
```

Comment: How does your script work? Does it get the sequence of start and limit from ajax. Say: (0, 20), (21, 20), (41,20) etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate this without the query. If you don't want more than 5000 results, this should work:

```
if (($start + $limit) <= 5000) {
    // Do query
}
else {
    // Don't do query, maximum limit reached
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view in your database wih the following syntax:

```
create view view_name as select * from table where id is not null order by desc LIMIT 5000
```

Then you will query the view for the ajax infinite scroll / pagination

```
select * from view_name where id is not null order by desc LIMIT :start, :limit
```

*Note: with the view your can use a simpler query, since the view already choose the good rows (with non null id), and order them.*

```
select * from view_name LIMIT :start, :limit
```